# classList.remove seems to crash

Tags: javascript, css

So basically I'm trying to make a transition.
Here's the error message Chrome Gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

```
function showDefuseContainer(currentPhase){
    var DefuseContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("Defuser");
    if(currentPhase == "defuse" || currentPhase == "over"){
        DefuseContainer.classList.add("show");
    }else{
        DefuseContainer.classList.remove("show");
    }
}
```

Comment: `DefuseContainer` is a *list* of elements (note the pluralized getElement**s**ByClassName). `classList` is a property of a *single* element.

Comment: use this instead: `var DefuseContainer = document.querySelector(".Defuser");`. Your currently getting a list of items

Comment: @TylerRoper `DefuseContainer ` will be list because `document.getElementsByClassName("Defuser");`

Comment: @DupinderSingh Sorry, I'm not following. I believe that's more or less exactly what I said, no?

Comment: yaa exactly, I was saying yes to you, that you are right this is `DefuseContainer`  array of elements

Comment: Are you trying to modify the `classList` of *all* instances of `Defuser`? Of just the first? Or just the last? Or is there only *one*? We need more information.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName() - returns a HTMLCollection - an array-like object.

Either use an id :

```
document.getElementById("DefuserID")
```

Or the querySelector to get only the first occurrence:

```
document.querySelector("Defuser")
```

Or select the first one in the HTMLCollection by it's index like so:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Defuser")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, so my suggestion is to use `DefuseContainer[0]` like

```
// function receiving currentPhase
function showDefuseContainer(currentPhase){
    var DefuseContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("Defuser");
    if(currentPhase == "defuse" || currentPhase == "over"){
        DefuseContainer[0].classList.add("show"); // if currentPhase  is defuse || over then add show class means show the Container
    }else{
        DefuseContainer[0].classList.remove("show"); // else remove the show class and hide the container
    }
}
```